# Start the HorizontalScrollView by some scrollX

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

How can I specify a value that when visible the HorizontalScrollView will be already scrolled by the value?

I already tried the scrollTo method, but it's only work on a post layout Context, I'm not able  to start the HorizontalScrollView on a specific position.

How can I do that?

Comment: How can someone vote down without saying anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this way, any better solution is also welcome:

```
    public void scrollWhenAvailable(final int x) {
        if (x == getScrollX())
            return;

        scrollTo(x, 0);

        postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollWhenAvailable(x);
            }
        }, 10);
    }
```

Comment: I had a similar problem right now. And I was able to solve it by writing setScrollX inside scrollView.post(new Runnable())  in my onCreate() but it didn't give any result if I write setScrollX outside this . Do you have any idea is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

you will probably have to use scrollTo anyway, since it does exactly what you want, albeit you may need to call it at the right time. (in some onPostSomething, i guess)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is unecessary to to a postDelayed, a simple post is sufficient since it will be executed after all the view dimensions have been calculated, you can even add this in onCreate(..).

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        scrollView.setScrollX(x);
    }
});
```

Also note that setScrollX is probably what you want to use if your SDK level is high enough.